# Change position of Excel VBA created barcode shape

Tags: excel, vba, barcode

I found this code that creates barcodes as a shape within Excel.

My problem is, that the created barcode always begins at the right side of the formula. For example if I use the =BarCodefunction(B2), I get the object created in C2. I need the barcode in B3.
I've tried changing the X, Y, but can't really get it to pop in place.

Also it seems to have a bug in the code. If I sometimes update a table in any workbook, it can automaticly create barcodes across different sheets and workbooks. Any help to what that is all about would also be helpful.

```
Option Explicit


Public Function BarCode_Function(Input_Cell As Range)
    '------------------< BarCode_Function() >------------------
    '< get Input >
    Dim wert As String
    wert = Input_Cell.Formula
    Dim CellID As String
    CellID = "BarCode_" & Input_Cell.Column & "_" & Input_Cell.Row

    Dim x As Integer, Y As Integer, Heigth As Integer
    x = Input_Cell.Left + Input_Cell.Width + 2

    Y = Input_Cell.Top + 2
    Heigth = Input_Cell.Height - 4
    '</ get Input >

    '< create Barcode 39 >
    paintCode39 wert, ActiveSheet, "Barcode_" & CellID, 1, x, Y, Heigth
    '</ create Barcode 39 >

    On Error Resume Next
    delete_Shape_Clones


    '< Ausgabe >
    BarCode_Function = ""
    '</ Ausgabe >
    '------------------</ BarCode_Function() >------------------
End Function


' -------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub paintCode39(ByVal Value As String, _
                       ByRef Sheet As Worksheet, _
                       ByVal Name As String, _
                       ByVal ScaleFactor As Integer, _
                       ByVal x As Integer, _
                       ByVal Y As Integer, _
                       ByVal Height As Integer _
                       )
    ' Skapa variabel
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim code As String
    Dim varArray() As Variant
    Dim iCount As Integer

    'Initiera positionsvariabeln

    'vid behov lägg till start och stoppa tecken till det värde som ska visas
    If Left(Value, 1) <> "*" Then Value = "*" & Value
    If Right(Value, 1) <> "*" Then Value = Value & "*"

    ' Bestäm om det redan finns en gammal version av streckkoden
    ' ligger på arbetsbladet.
    For Each sh In Sheet.Shapes
        If sh.Name = Name Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'Gå igenom värdet som ska visas karaktär för tecken
    For i = 1 To Len(Value)

        ' Koda nuvarande tecken enligt kartläggningstabellen
        'Exempel: A blir 1101010010110
        code = getCode(Mid(Value, i, 1))

        ' Kontrollera om giltig kodning hittades.
        If code = "" Then
            ' MsgBox "Streckkodstillverkning avbrutits.", _
             '      vbCritical, _
              '      "Odefinierad karaktär"
            Exit For
        End If

        ' gå genom baren genom baren
        For j = 1 To Len(code)
            ' Skapa nytt Shape-objekt med ScalFactor-bredd
            Set sh = Sheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                                           x, _
                                           Y, _
                                           ScaleFactor, _
                                           Height)

            ' X-Position för att öka bredden på ScalFactor
            x = x + ScaleFactor

            ' Färg svart eller vitt beroende på aktuell kodform
            If Mid(code, j, 1) = 1 Then
                ' Kode = 1 --> svart
                sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Else
                ' Kode = 0 --> Vit
                sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                sh.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If

            'Lägg till staplar i array för senare gruppering
            iCount = iCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To iCount)
            varArray(iCount) = sh.Name
        Next
    Next
group:
    'Gruppera alla tidigare skapade staplar till en enda grafik
    Set sh = Sheet.Shapes.Range(varArray).group

    ' Namn grupperad grafik
    sh.Name = Name
End Sub


Private Function getCode(ByVal Character As String) As String
    Dim code As String
    Select Case UCase(Character)
        Case "*"
            code = "1001011011010"
        Case "0"
            code = "1010011011010"
        Case "1"
            code = "1101001010110"
        Case "2"
            code = "1011001010110"
        Case "3"
            code = "1101100101010"
        Case "4"
            code = "1010011010110"
        Case "5"
            code = "1101001101010"
        Case "6"
            code = "1011001101010"
        Case "7"
            code = "1010010110110"
        Case "8"
            code = "1101001011010"
        Case "9"
            code = "1011001011010"
        Case "A"
            code = "1101010010110"
        Case "B"
            code = "1011010010110"
        Case "C"
            code = "1101101001010"
        Case "D"
            code = "1010110010110"
        Case "E"
            code = "1101011001010"
        Case "F"
            code = "1011011001010"
        Case "G"
            code = "1010100110110"
        Case "H"
            code = "1101010011010"
        Case "I"
            code = "1011010011010"
        Case "J"
            code = "1010110011010"
        Case "K"
            code = "1101010100110"
        Case "L"
            code = "1011010100110"
        Case "M"
            code = "1101101010010"
        Case "N"
            code = "1010110100110"
        Case "O"
            code = "1101011010010"
        Case "P"
            code = "1011011010010"
        Case "Q"
            code = "1010101100110"
        Case "R"
            code = "1101010110010"
        Case "S"
            code = "1011010110010"
        Case "T"
            code = "1010110110010"
        Case "U"
            code = "1100101010110"
        Case "V"
            code = "1001101010110"
        Case "W"
            code = "1100110101010"
        Case "X"
            code = "1001011010110"
        Case "Y"
            code = "1100101101010"
        Case "Z"
            code = "1001101101010"
        Case "-"
            code = "1001010110110"
        Case "."
            code = "1100101011010"
        Case " "
            code = "1001101011010"
        Case "$"
            code = "1001001001010"
        Case "/"
            code = "1001001010010"
        Case "+"
            code = "1001010010010"
        Case "%"
            code = "1010010010010"
        Case Else
            code = ""
    End Select

    getCode = code
End Function


Private Sub delete_Shape_Clones()
    '-------------------< delete_Shape_Clones() >---------------
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Set Sheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim iShape As Integer
    Dim nShapes As Integer
    nShapes = Sheet.Shapes.Count

    For iShape = 1 To nShapes

        Dim objShape As Shape
        Dim iLoop As Integer

        For iLoop = iShape + 1 To nShapes
            If Sheet.Shapes(iLoop).Name = Sheet.Shapes(iShape).Name Then
                Sheet.Shapes(iLoop).Delete
                nShapes = nShapes - 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    '-------------------</ delete_Shape_Clones() >---------------
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting generation of barcodes completely Excel-internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change 3 code rows for X, Y, and Height by these, and the barcode is shown in the cell below (instead of next cell to the right):

```
X = Input_Cell.Offset(1, 0).Left + 2
Y = Input_Cell.Offset(1, 0).Top + 2
Heigth = Input_Cell.Offset(1, 0).Height - 4
```

---

As the code addresses the `ActiveSheet` (which is the varying active sheet you currently see), it's not bound to a specific sheet. If you want it to work on a specific sheet only, exchange `ActiveSheet` by e. g. `ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("My Barcode Sheet")`

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.worksheets worked like a charm, thank you. And now I got it working.  thank you very much!